# Graylog ; How to limit extractors application to a subset of sources

Tags: graylog2, graylog

Trying to use extractors within Graylog, I cannot find a way to limit the pattern matching to one source.

Basically I do a split&Index search to extract a field but I want this extractors to be used only for a subset of my sources.
Documentation seems poor for this.

Any Idea ?

Thanks
Loïc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this cannot be easily done. There're two options: pipelines and separate inputs. Obviously, if you capture different sources in different inputs then you prevent this problem.

The second solution is to use Pipelines (as of v2). Here's [the author confirming this](https://graylog.ideas.aha.io/ideas/GL2E-I-436):

> This is possible since Graylog 2.0 by using pipeline rules.
>   http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.1/pages/pipelines.html

---

**p.s.** I thought it might be possible to store and extract from the full message, but couldn't figure how to first cut the json prior to extraction. A sample message coming from a docker container might look like this (sending logs over syslog to Graylog):

```
<30>1 2016-11-26T22:22:38.951321+01:00 www.example.com docker 19459 - -  {"name":"my-awesome-app","hostname":"docker24.example.com","pid":1,"level":30,"msg":"happily serving customers","time":"2016-11-26T21:22:38.950Z"}
```

So the entire field is not a proper JSON and Graylog JSON extractor would fail. You have your source here - `www.example.com`, so it's possible to configure the extractor to only run when this matches, but then the question is how to parse only the JSON section..

Comment: thanks. We're bascically using Syslog as single inputs. We'll try to separate sources directly via syslog using different port. as it seems the simple way because I don't want parsers to parse useless data.